# Objective C object by string name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsobject

Is it possible to find the object named with specific string.

For example i can use that in php

```
$objectname="foo";
$foo="bar";
echo $$objectname="bar";
```

is this possible? objectbyname would a proper function for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be possible if you stored named objects as properties or in some sort of dictionary. Then you could do something like this:

```
// Put object into dictionary
[dictionaryWithObjects setValue:someNamedObject forKey:@"someNamedObject"];

// and then retrieve it
id object = [dictionaryWithObjects valueForKey:@"someNamedObject"];
```

And I'm not sure ObjectiveC supports that level of metaprogramming.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look quite as it does in PHP but, yes, it is possible to get a class from a string. You use the [`NSClassFromString`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString) function.

For example the following two lines are equivalent:

```
id a = [[NSClassFromString(@"NSString") alloc] init];
id a = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSClassFromString()` to get a class, but for specific instances of an object I don't think this is possible.