# Evaulate NSString and execute as Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, loops, nsstring, concatenation

This might be a completely ridiculous question, but is it possible to use a `NSString` as a substitute for a line of code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10: i++){    
    NSString *cam = @"locXCamProfileSwitch";
    ["%@", cam setOn:YES];
]
```

Also is it possible to concantinate the index `i` into the replacement of the `X`?

Comment: No, but you can access a method or property using a string - what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you trying to set 10 switches to state ON? That's not the right way to do that. Add them all to an array and use that.

Comment: @Drummer thats exactly whhat I'm trying to do, can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not generally possible (as far as I know), but it's possible to access ivars, properties, classes and methods by using strings.

- Instance variables and properties can be accessed like this:

  ```
  [self valueForKey:@"key"];
  ```
- Classes can be referenced like this:

  ```
  Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"MyClass");
  [cls aClassMethod];
  ```
- Methods can be used like this:

  ```
  SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"myMethod:");
  [self performSelector:selector];
  ```

To replace a placeholder in a string with a number you can use a formatter:

```
NSString *cam = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"loc%dCamProfileSwitch", i];
```

That being said, it's never a good idea to have numbered variable names.

**Use an array instead:**

```
int switchCount = 10;
NSMutableArray *switches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:switchCount];
for (int i = 0; i < switchCount; i++) {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 10+i*30, 70, 40); // or something like that.
    UISwitch *sw = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    sw.tag = i;
    [sw addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) 
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:sw];
    [switches addObject:sw];
}
self.switches = [NSArray arrayWithArray:switches];  // assuming you have a property "switches".
```

Then you can simply iterate over it:

```
for (UISwitch *switch in self.switches) {
    [switch setOn:YES];
}
```

And be notified when one of them changes like this:

```
- (void)switchChanged:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender; // the switch that changed.
    int tag = theSwitch.tag;  // number of switch that changed.
    // do something....
}
```

Comment: how can i add all my switches to an array? . . . . sorry

Answer (score 1):

See [Objective C object by string name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972607/objective-c-object-by-string-name)

But essentially you're doing it wrong. Create an array of 10 switches and iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

Add all your switches to an array and iterate through that using its indices.